# Image of the multiplication of a function by a scalar

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

$f$ is a linear function that maps from a vector space $E$ to $E'$. How can I prove that $\operatorname{Im}f = \operatorname{Im} \alpha f$?

Lets say that $f(a,b,c) = (2a, 2b, 2c)$, the image is $(2a, 2b, 2c)$.
Now $2\cdot f(a,b,c)$ has image $(4a, 4b, 4c)$ which is not the same...

Comment: You are asked to show an equality of sets, not of functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because clearly $\operatorname{Im}\alpha f\subseteq\operatorname{Im}f$, and the reverse inclusion is true because $f=\alpha^{-1}(\alpha f)$.

Comment: There is no assurance that $\alpha$ is non-zero.

Comment: It was implicit. If $\alpha=0$, you can't have $\operatorname{Im}f=\operatorname{Im}\alpha f$ unless $f=0$.

Answer (score 3):

If $\alpha = 0$, you can't. Consider $f$ the identify map on $\mathbb{R}$, for instance.

On the other hand, if $\alpha$ has a multiplicative inverse (in a field, if $\alpha$ is nonzero), you can prove this.

Claim: for every scalar $\alpha$ and linear $f$, we have $Im(\alpha f) \subseteq Im(f)$. Proof: suppose $y \in Im(\alpha f)$. Take $x$ such that $\alpha f(x) = y$. Then $f(\alpha x) = y$. Then $y \in Im(f)$.

If $\alpha$ is invertible, we have $f = \alpha^{-1} \alpha f$ and thus $Im(f) = Im(\alpha^{-1} \alpha f) \subseteq Im(\alpha f) \subseteq Im(f)$ and therefore $Im(\alpha f) = Im(f)$.